# Can oauth2 "state" parameter be used to avoid using session cookies to identify user

Tags: csrf, oauth, authorization, oauth2

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1 states:

> 4.1.1.  Authorization Request"
>
> "state"
>
> RECOMMENDED.  An opaque value used by the client to maintain
> state between the request and callback.  The authorization
> server includes this value when redirecting the user-agent back
> to the client.  The parameter SHOULD be used for preventing
> cross-site request forgery as described in Section 10.12.

Is it safe to use a "state" parameter I generate (`uuid/v4`) in OAuth2 authorization request besides CSRF protection to identify the user in the provider callback in the authorization flow? Thus making the oauth2 flow "stateless" and don't require "sticky-sessions" for the load-balancer.

Currently, when a user starts the OAuth2 flow (visits login page) I create a unique `auth-request-id` and `state` for him and store it in Redis and send the `auth-request-id` in the cookies.

After the user logins into the provider (Google or Facebook) in the callback request, I try to find the user's session from the `auth-request-id` cookie in Redis and validate whether a session exists and that the received `state` matches the one I sent (against CSRF attacks).

**Wondering, can I skip creating the `auth-request-id` cookie and identify the user in the callback by the `state`?** Given the logic, if no matching `state` can be found in Redis, presume the state to be invalid and all Redis stored `state` has a 5 min expiry time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe You cannot do this securely.

Malicious actor can freely obtain redirects using your application. Now if he manage to make a unsuspecting victim to open redirect address then the victim will see that Your application is asking for access. If he grant access he will be redirected back to you, if you use only state to identify him then you just assigned victim resources to malicious actor account in your app.